# Improve performance of a loop with non-numerical operations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, where I should apply some operations on rows in each group. I create subsets in a loop with rows from specific categories, but it is too inefficient. .groupby().apply() is even slover. How can performance be improved here?

(e.g. There are events with the same id, but different timestamps and activities. I create a new dataframe with new columns "PreviousActivity", "NextActivity", "Loop")

EventLog. Initial table(Events are already sorted by Timestamp):

| CaseId | ActivityName | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Invoice | 2001-12-13 15:26:00 |
| 0 | Payment | 2001-12-20 17:05:11 |
| 0 | Receipt | 2001-12-20 18:05:11 |
| 0 | Receipt | 2001-12-20 18:06:11 |
| 1 | Item Deletion | 2001-12-13 15:29:14 |

New table (Events):

| CaseId | ActivityName | PreviousActivity | NextActivity | Timestamp | Loop | EventId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Invoice | Start Activity | Payment | 2001-12-13 15:26:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | Payment | Invoice | Receipt | 2001-12-20 17:05:11 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | Receipt | Payment | Receipt | 2001-12-20 18:05:11 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | Receipt | Payment | End Activity | 2001-12-20 18:06:11 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | Item Deletion | Start Activity | End Activity | 2001-12-13 15:29:14 | 0 | 4 |

My code:

```
 def get_events_df(event_log):
    unique_cases = event_log["CaseId"].unique().tolist()

    columns = [
        "CaseId",
        "ActivityName",
        "Timestamp",
        "EventId",
        "PreviousActivity",
        "NextActivity",
    ]

    events = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    event_log["EventId"] = event_log.index

    for i, val in enumerate(unique_cases):

        case_subset = event_log.loc[
            event_log["CaseId"] == unique_cases[i]
        ]

            # Add Previous Activity
            if row["EventId"] == case_subset["EventId"].iloc[0]:
                case_subset.at[index, "PreviousActivity"] = "Start Activity"
            else:
                case_subset.at[index, "PreviousActivity"] = case_subset[
                    "ActivityName"
                ][index - 1]

            # Add Next Activity
            if row["EventId"] == case_subset["EventId"].iloc[-1]:
                case_subset.at[index, "NextActivity"] = "End Activity"
            else:
                case_subset.at[index, "NextActivity"] = case_subset["ActivityName"][
                    index + 1
                ]

            # Loop detection
            if (
                case_subset.at[index, "PreviousActivity"]
                == case_subset.at[index, "ActivityName"]
            ):
                case_subset.at[index, "Loop"] = 1
            elif (
                case_subset.at[index, "ActivityName"]
                == case_subset.at[index, "NextActivity"]
            ):
                case_subset.at[index, "Loop"] = 1
            else:
                case_subset.at[index, "Loop"] = 0

        events = pd.concat([events, case_subset])

    return events
```

Comment: what is eventid, how it is calculated. its not part of the orginal df but referenced in the code

Comment: @Naveed It's before the loop statement:     event_log["EventId"] = event_log.index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance problem has been solved. I worked simply with python lists and dictionaries. Using pandas is excessive here.

```
def get_events_df(event_log):
    event_log_dict = event_log.to_dict("records")
    output_list = []
    events = []
    event_log_dict = sorted(event_log_dict, key=operator.itemgetter("CaseId"))
    for key, value in tqdm(itertools.groupby(event_log_dict, key=operator.itemgetter("CaseId"))):
        value = list(value)
        output_list.append(value)

        # Create events
        for i, item in enumerate(value):
            if i == 0:
                item["PreviousActivity"] = "Start Activity"
            else:
                item["PreviousActivity"] = value[i - 1].get("ActivityName")

            if i == event_count - 1:
                item["NextActivity"] = "End Activity"
            else:
                item["NextActivity"] = value[i + 1].get("ActivityName")

            if item["PreviousActivity"] == item["ActivityName"] or item["NextActivity"] == item["ActivityName"]:
                item["Loop"] = 1
            else:
                item["Loop"] = 0

    events = pd.DataFrame(events)

    return events
```